# Custom methods for pandas df, that selects prespecified column by column name

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to write a custom method for the the `pd.DataFrame` class. That would allow me to directly place new values at prespecified location.

```py
class myDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def func1(self, row, value):
        self.df.at[row,"prespecified_column_name"] = value
```

like in the example above where I only have to specify the value and the row to be set, but the column is always the same.
The problem `self.df` does not exist. So I was wondering, how I would access columns of the DataFrame within the class using a column name.

Before people complain about this being not very efficient: This is obviosuly a reduced example.

Comment: *but the column is always the same* - so what's the problem of using a constant column name?

Comment: In this case I want to streamline how different parts of my project interact. 
And in my case it is much easier for me to have the DataFrame class to hold the information on where to store the value. Rather than the script in which the dataframe is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am unsure if your solution is really the best option that depends on what you're trying to achieve. The issue you are facing is due to that fact that you inherit from pd.DataFrame. Therefore you are not trying to alter `self.df` but `self`.

This should work:

```
class myDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def func1(self, row, value):
        self.at[row,"prespecified_column_name"] = value
```

or you could create a new class that has a data frame as attribute:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
    def func1(self, row, value):
        self.df.at[row,"prespecified_column_name"] = value
```

Comment: Yeah that makes in hindsight very much sense. Thanks for the answer it worked as you described

Comment: If I wanted to add variables